# While updating in SVN - getting HTTP status 502 Proxy Error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subversion-edge

I am having an SVN server in India location. I have totally 6 six servers in the different country. The SVN repository will update every 30 seconds in all Edge server. In Germany Edge servers I am facing an svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 502 'Proxy Error' on 'repo name'.  There is no gateway or proxy. The total size of the repository is 146GB+.

Kindly suggest what will cause this type of issues.

From server side apache configuration httpd.conf Timeout 600. and client side enables the ~/.subversion/server -> http-bulk-updates and http-timeout.

Comment: I think you're going to have to do more debugging. Can you log into that edge server and try making web requests from it to the origin server? Can you check for any proxy config there, or e.g. tcpdump the outbound packets to check that they're going where you expect and not to a proxy? Can you check the web logs of the origin server to see if it's serving 502s?

Comment: Dear @Rup, Thank you for your suggestion. I can able to get the response from Edge server to origin server via the web request. There is no proxy is configured in the servers and checked the tcpdump has received the packets as I expected. But still i am facing the proxy error.

Comment: In Network Monitoring device (river bird) we have whitelisted an Edge server IP. When trying a new checkout it is showing svn: E000110: Error running context: Connection timed out.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have done the modification in subversion config files. In ~/.subversion/server file having a global configuration. I have an updated the `http-bulk-updates` option in Edge server as per the https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html URL. Also, `From the Network traffic monitor, we have a bypassed the server and client SVN.` After only I have an get the proper response from Edge server side.